# Import Range broke

Tags: import, google-sheets, range

I have a sheet called Julie in a Google sheets Workbook? with some data on it and another sheet (sheet 2) next to it that I want to use to analyse the data

I copied the spreadsheet url but all it ever comes up with is that it cant find range or sheet, this is even though its next to it!!! do Google sheets actually work or is it just a scam to help you commit suicide. WTF is wrong with pastelink god only knows This is just rubbish

=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17k5JJM_zoTCkwUP-Ab2OYWRIFC0pvkcIvnSyeERLh4A/edit#gid=209247117","Julie Link!a1:f200")

Answer (score 0):

If the sheet is called `Julie` don't expect IMPORTRANGE to pull cell data from "Julie Link".